# Date Calculation

Tags: sql-server, date-time

I have a Date range,

2020-11-25 as Start Date

2020-12-10 as End date

I wanted to get the count of December month days in the above Date range if I am looking for December month.(I need the output as  10)

If I pass the input as November, then I need the November month days in the above that range.(I need the output as 6)

Answer (score 0):

To get days in November:

```
select datediff(d,'2020-11-25',eomonth('2020-11-25'))+1
```

To get days in December:

```
select datediff(d,dateadd(d,1,eomonth('2020-12-10',-1)),'2020-12-10')+1
```